# Exponential Distribution - Lifetime of Chips

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that the lifetime of a particular kind of chip is **exponentially distributed**, and it is observed that the chip is as likely to fail before $5,000$ hours as it is to last longer than $5,000$ hours.

What is the **average** life time of the chip ?

I don't know for sure whether
this one uses $$\text{Expectation} = \text{mean} = \frac1\lambda$$
or whether to let $$P[x<5000] = P[x>5000]$$ and then find the $\lambda$.

There is another subquestion that I couldn't do it

How many chips of this kind must be sampled until you are 99% sure to find the one with lifetime more than 10,000 hours

Comment: Yes, compute $P(X<5000)$ and $P(X>5000)$ as functions of $\lambda$, and solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: So the mean is not 5000 ?

Comment: Nope. The median is 5000, but for the exponential distribution the median is not equal to the mean.

Comment: I've just add another following question, could you help me with that pls ?
How many chips of this kind must be sampled until you are 99% sure to find the one with lifetime more than 10,000 hours

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that P[X>5000]=P[X<5000]
Deduce that median is $5000$
And use it to find the parameter $\lambda$.by integrating from $0 to 5000$ and equalling it to $1/2$.
After this just take the reciprocal that your mean i guess you should get
$$5000/log2$$ as your mean

Comment: First I thought I can just do Expectation = mean = 5000 = 1/$\lambda$ then find the $\lambda$ as mean

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0=5000$. From 
$$\Bbb{P}(X\le x_0)=1-e^{-\lambda x_0}=\Bbb{P}(X> x_0)=e^{-\lambda x_0}$$
we'll find $e^{-\lambda x_0}=\frac{1}{2}$ and finally $\lambda =\frac{\log 2}{x_0}$.

So the mean lifetime is
$$
\Bbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{5000}{\log{2}}
$$

**Note** Observe that $5000$ is the median of $X$, that is $\frac{\log{2}}{\lambda}=5000$. so you can find the mean from the median $
\Bbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{5000}{\log{2}}
$.